# update datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2012

i have the following code, what  want it to do is update when i add new records to my table from a separate form, at the moment i am getting all the table data, but if i add new data it is not visible here, but is saved in the table, i have to close the program and run it again for the saved data to be visible in the datagridview. my question is how do i update the datagridview, in order for the table info to be there at all times.
The code i have is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace project
{
    public partial class frmViewBookings : Form
    {
        public frmViewBookings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 mainpage = new Form3();
            mainpage.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void frmViewBookings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet1.Booking' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.bookingTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet1.Booking);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `.DataBind()` after updating?

Comment: What does the `Binding Look Like`? can you show where you are a declaring `usersDataSet1` looks like you are missing some code here

Comment: hmm... i think i am confused, @DJKRAZE - i had simply added the datagridview from the toolbox and then simply chose the data source. this is all i have done

Comment: sounds like you are not Binding then just like I stated initially

Comment: how do i bind the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add/Edit your existing method in frmViewBookings:

```
private void frmViewBookings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet1.Booking' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    UpdateData();

}

public void UpdateData()
{
    this.bookingTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet1.Booking);
}
```

Then call `UpdateData()` from your other Form

In your other form, add a property that holds the first form:

```
public partial class frmBooking : Form
{
    public frmViewBookings myBookingsFrm = null;
}
```

Then when you create the frmBooking form, do:

```
frmBooking frmNewBookingFrm = new frmBooking();
frmNewBookingFrm.myBookingsFrm = this;//or whatever reference to the first frmViewBookings is
```

So after you insert the new record inside frmBooking, call:

```
myBookingsFrm.UpdateData();
```

Comment: thanks, how do i call the "updateData()" in my frmBooking form?

Comment: i have 2 forms, 1 is the one above, and the other is frmBooking, where i make the actual booking.... i want to make the booking on frmBooking then the data to update in the datagridview (the form above) currently data is stored after a booking is made on the frmBooking but it isnt visible on the datagridview, unless i close the program and run it again. this is what i need help with. thanks

Comment: That is exactly what the code I provided does. If you provide the code for frmBooking I can edit it for you.

Comment: private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=..

            String query =
                "INSERT INTO [Booking] values ('"
                + Facility.Text etc

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         
            con.Close();
 
               MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Booked");
               Form3 mainPage = new Form3();
               mainPage.Show();
               this.Close();

Comment: see my edited code above. Basically, your frmBooking needs to have a reference to the frmViewBookings that you want to update. in btnConfirm_Click, you need to call the UpdateData() method on the frmViewBookings object. It also seems you have 3 forms, not 2. The more code you give us the easier it is to help you.

Comment: i don't understand where i am supposed to put "frmBooking frmNewBookingFrm = new frmBooking();
frmNewBookingFrm.myBookingsFrm = this;" its getting pretty confusing now. sorry i know im wasting your time, ill try figuring it out another way,

Comment: thanks for the help, ill mark your answer as correct answer though.